# Syntax for calling child relationship with a condition on the parent in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a model called 'Tag' which has a self-referencing 'hasMany' relationship on itself. So for example I have a tag called UK and this 'has many' child tags called London, Liverpool, Manchester etc.

Here is the relationship in the Tag model file:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tag', 'tag_parent');
}
```

I simply want to get the list of child cities from the parent 'UK' tag. So I have this code:

```
$cities = Tag::where('title', 'UK')->get()->children;
```

I am getting an error saying children is unknown. The docs say I should do this which works as expected.

```
$cities = Tag::find($id)->children;
```

So how do I get that list of child cities with the 'where' condition? I thought Tag::find($id) was just a shortcut for Tag::where('id', $id)->get()?

**UPDATE**

Exact error:

```
ErrorException in TagController.php line 28:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$children
```

Comment: Please post the exact error you receive. Also, try a dd(Tag::find($id)) and see what you get

Comment: [find()](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_find) seems to be returning a Collection object. Are there multiple rows with the same ID in your database?

Comment: Hi Dave, find() works as expected and does return the correct data in Collection form, but it uses a numeric id. I need to find by 'title' rather than the numeric id, so it's the first example I'm having issues with, not the one with the find() method.

Comment: You can't query a model on a `hasMany` relationship like that. You should load it this way: `Tag::with('children')->where('title', 'UK')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

As @revo mentioned, use the `with` method. It's called [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) in Laravel.

```
Tag::with('children')->where('title', 'UK')->get();
```

This should gives you all the tags with `title = UK`, plus all the children that's related to each of every individual tags.

Answer (score 0):

`get()` will always return a `Collection`, even if there is only one record. Since `Collection`s do not have a `children` attribute, you get the "undefined property" error you are seeing.

The reason `find()` worked is because it returned a `Tag` model, which does have the `children` attribute.

If `title` is unique, you can simple change from `get()` to `first()`. `first()` will always return a `Model` instance; `get()` will always return a `Collection`.

```
$cities = Tag::where('title', 'UK')->first()->children;
```

If `title` is not unique, then you will need to loop through the `Collection` of returned `Tag`s, and act on each set of children accordingly.

```
$tags = Tag::with('children')->where('title', 'UK')->get();
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $cities = $tag->children;
    // do something with this set of children.
}
```

NB: the `with('children')` is added purely for performance reasons ([eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)). It does not affect the rest of the code, and could be removed without having to change anything else.